# DirectoryIndex doesn't work

Tags: apache2, indexing

I use apache2 to host a site. There are both index.html and index.php in my directory.

I open the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and add a line:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
```

Then restart apache2. But when I open `localhost/~username`, it accesses the index.html.

I look around but can't find problem. My httpd.conf is empty and I don't have .htaccess file.

Where may the setting hide?

**Edit**: After I modified `/etc/apache2/mods-availiable/dir.conf`, it finds the index.php.

But WHY the apache2.conf can't overwrite dir.conf?!

Comment: If you temporarily remove index.html from the directory (eg rename it) does it find index.php?

Comment: Yes. If I rename it to index.htm, apache find index.php

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have the exact same problem where if I edit the dir.conf file, it works, but anywhere else (except for htaccess), it doesn't override it :(

Answer (score 1):

I think `mod_dir` isn't loaded, try to command `sudo a2enmod dir` and `service apache2 restart`

Comment: This is not an answer to this question; you just gave it to another one?

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named .htaccess in the directory where you want this behavior to occur. Inside the .htaccess file, put a single line beginning with DirectoryIndex followed by the list of filenames that you want Apache to serve first when a directory has been requested, like so:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm index.phtml start.html
```

The above directive must be all on a single line in the .htaccess file.