# DirectoryIndex seemingly ignored by apache2

Tags: apache2, directoryindex

I'm installing Wordpress and getting the problem where it doesn't find index.php.  Of course, if I type it explicitly then it's fine.  The problem is somehow that DirectoryIndex is not right.  I look in mods-enabled/dir.conf and it says:

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
  DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml index.htm
</IfModule>
```

Which appears to be correct.  But it doesn't work.  I thought maybe some other file somewhere is overriding this but if so, it isn't in mods-enabled as I grepped that folder.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is mod_dir actually loaded?

More likely to be caused by a bogus rewriterule preventing mod_dir from ever seeing a request for a directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DirectoryIndex doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509549/directoryindex-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0):

I think mod_dir isn't loaded,try to command  "sudo a2enmod dir" and "service apache2 restart"